# Kotlin, project structure

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I am writing a kotlin port of glm and I'm gonna use it also for java projects.

In these java projects, I'd like to call, for example, `glm.mul(...)`:

where `mul()` is a function of the `mat2x2_operators` interface

Now, if I have `glm` declared as an interface and its companion object extends `mat2x2_operators` in this way

```
interface glm {
   companion object :
       mat2x2_operators,
```

I have `mul` available on java via

`glm.Companion.mul(...)`

If I try to declare `glm` as an object:

`glm.INSTANCE.mul(...)`

the reason I don't write `mul` directly under `glm` is because I have hundred of functions that I'd like to keep ordered in different places (interfaces), such as `mat2x2_operators` precisely

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Sorry,  accomplish what? Maybe it you give us an example of usage, it will be clearer.

Comment: Calling `glm.mul()`

Comment: @voddan I think that's not allowed in interfaces (as of 1.0.5) (however, the use of an interface is questionable here anyway)

Comment: You are right. But this is not allowed in Java ether.

Comment: I can `@JvmStatic` only on functions in named objects or companion objects in classes